# android why this button is not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

I don't know why the last two buttons is not clickable, I used the background (that i set to them ) many time and it works with another layouts, I am sure that the wrong is something like foucable or clickable but i don't know where exactly .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_selectRestaurant"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                    android:text="@string/b_selectRestaurant" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_orderMeal_isSelectRestaurant"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/iv_isSelected"
                    android:src="@drawable/x" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_selectMealItems"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                    android:text="@string/b_select_MealItems" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_orderMeal_isSelectMealItems"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/iv_isSelected"
                    android:src="@drawable/x" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_selectPayMethod"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
                    android:text="@string/b_selectPayMethod" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_orderMeal_isSelectPayMethod"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/iv_isSelected"
                    android:src="@drawable/x" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_checkBasket"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/b_check_basket" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_orderMeal_errorMessage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/tv_orderMeal_errorMessage"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:text="@string/b_send"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_orderMeal_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
                android:text="@string/b_cancel"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I am talking about the last two buttons

#### java

```
b_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_orderMeal_send);
        b_send.setOnClickListener(this);
        b_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_orderMeal_cancel);
        b_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
```

#### on click

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      case R.id.b_orderMeal_cancel:
        Toast.makeText(this, "roma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        break;          
    }
```

#### note

the toast doesn't appear

Comment: And how do you know they are not clickable? where is your java code?

Comment: Hope you added the code for OnClickListener for the last two buttons. Please check oyour code and confirm

Comment: You should add some logs or somthing in onClick, else how will you know is it clickable or not?

Comment: pls post the entire implementation of onClick. what are you using in switch statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't know why the last two buttons is not clickable, I used the
>   background (that i set to them ) many time and it works with another
>   layouts, I am sure that the wrong is something like foucable or
>   clickable but i don't know where exactly .

I think your `XML` design is OK in all ways so problem is most likely in `Java`. Most likely you forgot to register `OnClickListener` for your `Button(s)`.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_orderMeal_send);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Click event works.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }));
```

Or you can use `OnClickListener` interface and then

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.b_orderMeal_send:
         Toast.makeText(this, "Click event works.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: my activity is implements onclicklistenr

Comment: I dont know where is the problem , i am confused about this issue

Comment: Check my updated answer. I recommend to compare int values with switch than equals method...

Comment: i alread using switch case but sorry i didn't show you that , sorry , it still not working ,  I already did all your code,

Comment: it must works because it works for me. Copy my code and clean and rebuild your project and try it again.

Comment: sorry sajomn_d, i make the another answer as accept because he mention to it first, i hope i could accept more than one ansew,er really sorry, i like you , thank a lot

Comment: this is not true but... i wrote here first answer with working code. and i saw like he edited answer after mine.

Comment: @sajmon_d first thing, I edited my answer when OP posted onClick implementation and I saw he missed .show method that I mentions in answer. You can not just start answering question in the air without even getting into view of code of OP. I asked user2059935 to post code and I waited until i figured out what is missing, then only i posted my answer with mentioning that he missed .show method, unlike you who just created an in the first place without getting into code, then keep updating ur answer, this is not good  and not justifiable too.

Comment: ok man sorry for this "misunderstanding". But when i did read question  first idea was that is something wrong with event listener(this is in most cases) so i started writing answer with one update. Then i saw your code man...

Answer (score 2):

Some times **Emulator** will make the problem so I would like to intimate you guys to use a Real Android device for checking/running your Application

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `onClick()` method with below one and let us know about logcat.
**it seems you are trying to show `toast` but missing `.show()` method to show the toast.**
Try below code and let us know

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if(v.equals(b_send)){
     Toast.makeText(this,"b_send clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Log.d("TEMP TAG","b_send clicked");
 } else if(v.equals(b_cancel)){ 
    Toast.makeText(this,"b_cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.d("TEMP TAG","b_cancel clicked");
      }

  }
```

Comment: whis is the deverent ? i always make switch case, here where is the wrong ? any way i will try your solution

Comment: Check it again, you are missing .show() on toast.makeText method, and implement View.onClickListener interface in your activity.

Comment: And you can use switch or equal, result gonna same. So no worries.

Comment: But i do not recommend to use equals method for this goal. Its dirty and there is better and more clean solution.

Comment: @user2059935 Welcome,  if it was the .show() problem you should mark my answer as accepted,as I clearly mention that in a very first place, No? nyways happy coding :)

Comment: i accept your answer, i just didn't see that you have edited your questions

Comment: @sajmon_d oh how it is dirty to use equals  instead of Switch cases, both are equally good and working. and sorry i dint knew that Google appointed you to recommend, nyways thanks. :)

Comment: @user2059935 you do not need to write android:clickable="true" for buttons they are by default clickable.

Answer (score 1):

set clickable = true in the xml for your button and try this in your code.

```
findViewById(R.id.b_orderMeal_send).setOnClickListener(commonClickListener);
findViewById(R.id.b_orderMeal_cancel).setOnClickListener(commonClickListener);


private OnClickListener commonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int selectedItemId = v.getId();
    switch (selectedItemId) {
    case R.id.b_orderMeal_send:
        Toast.makeText(this, "roma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case R.id.b_orderMeal_cancel:
    Toast.makeText(this, "roma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing kept happening to me but my situation was a little different. First the buttons were working fine and both were clickable then all of a sudden after a couple of relaunches they completely stopped working.

I simply `Quit` the `Emulator` then relaunched it and the buttons started working again